# In Gmail, how do I create a contact from a recipient of an email?

Tags: gmail, google-contacts

In Gmail, how do I create a contact from a recipient of an email? For sender, there is 'Add   to Contact List' but there doesn't appear to be anything similar for the To: or Cc: fields.

Is there an easier way than creating the contacts manually?

Answer (score 14):

It's very simple, at least in the current version of Gmail.

1. Hover the mouse cursor over the recipient's name in the default message view until a pop-up card appears
2. Click `Add to contacts` on the pop-up card

Answer (score 7):

This is a little bit of a pain, and I'm not 100% sure about it, but it seems to work in my tests.

If you click the name of the person you want to add as a contact while viewing the message, there is an option to click their e-mail address to send them a message. Click that, then discard the message. Click their name again in the original; there is an option under "More" for "contact details". Click that and you can add the other stuff you want and add them to a real group.

It appears that sending--or at least, starting to send--a message to an e-mail address puts it into your contacts under "All Contacts".

---

Google has added several improvements to Gmail since I originally posted this. [drnbv's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/26261/354) is much more useful.

Answer (score 2):

Open the Conversion in the Standard View of GMail in a supported browser.

See this Screen shot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open the conversation, and to the immediate right of the "Reply" button of the message you are concerned about, there is a pull down menu.  Select "Add *emailaddress* to Contacts list".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem except I had the list of about 15 contacts that I wanted to add as contacts and add as a group.  I did not want to have hover over each name and individually add them and then add them all to a contact list after.  I found a quick solution, here is what I did:

Beside the list of recipients I pressed the 'show details' down arrow.  Then I copied the list of recipient emails.

I went to the contacts view for Gmail. Clicked Add to Contacts and pasted the emails in.

At the left hand side I expanded the list of contact groups and clicked "New Group...".  I followed the steps to make a new group.  Then I clicked the "Add to contact list" button and pasted in the list of contacts again.

Done!