# How to add an email address from a gmail message to my google contacts

Tags: gmail, google-contacts, contacts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Gmail, how do I create a contact from a recipient of an email?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/11699/in-gmail-how-do-i-create-a-contact-from-a-recipient-of-an-email)

There's a sidebar that pops up offering to add people on the message to my circles, but not my address book.  Is there a way other than cut-n-pasting that lets me take one or more addresses from an email (to/from/cc) and put them in my address book?  I'm looking for something analogous to the 'take address' feature in `pine`/`alpine`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from the "Add to Circles", the side pane also has the options to add the contact.

See this screenshot:

[image: Add people you receive emails from to your Gmail Contacts]

Comment: Ah, buried -- thanks for pointing that out!